# XML/VBA extracting data from multi page table

Tags: xml, vba

I am attempting, in vain, to extract data, using VBA & XML, from a multi page table from the Ireland Central Bank website ([Central Bank Website](http://registers.centralbank.ie/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx?searchEntity=FundServiceProvider&searchType=Name&searchText=&registers=6%2C29%2C44%2C45)). I have been successful in extracting this using IE. However, I stumbled across code to extract web page tables using XML and can see the benefits in using this method, i.e. it is quicker.

My question is, can I use the XML method to extract data from a multi page table or am I limited to automating IE to complete this.

The XML code I've used is as follows:

```
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xml
         .Open "GET", "http://registers.centralbank.ie/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx?searchEntity=FundServiceProvider&searchType=Name&searchText=&registers=6%2c29%2c44%2c45", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```

This code will extract the data on the first page of the web page that loads but I cannot figure out how to extract the remainder (total of 57 pages). The url does not change so it's not as easy as incrementing the page number.

I do not have a lot of experience with extracting data from web tables so I'd appreciate any help here.

Thanks,
Alan

Note: this has been cross posted to [MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1022235-extracting-data-through-xml-multi-page-web-page-table.html)

Comment: The pagination is handled with a Javascript `POST` request. It's not possible to load the next page with an instance of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` since it doesn't compile/execute the script from the page.

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks Florent, if that means that I have to use IE to scrape the information then so be it, just wanted to be sure. Thanks for taking a look